# Does the Work-Energy Theorem still apply when an object, starting at rest, moves and is still at rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

The Work-Energy Theorem as described in my physics learning module is
"The Work-Energy Theorem states that the net mechanical work done on an object is equal to the change in the object's kinetic energy." But, I was wondering, if the work energy theorem applies universally (or that is what I am assuming), then how would it apply if I lift a book at rest from the ground, and set it atop a bookshelf. Work (by the definition W=fd) is being done, but by the work-energy theorem, work is not being done.
Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Yes, the work-energy theorem applies universally, but it must be applied correctly. When you lift a book there are multiple forces in play, including whatever force you apply, but also the force due to gravity. You must be sure to remember that it is the *net force* that changes the kinetic energy.

Comment: Further, it is the integral of the net force over the distance that matter: $W_{net} = \int \vec{F}_{net}\cdot \vec {dx} = \Delta KE$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take the book at rest on the ground and bring it to rest atop the bookshelf a height $h$ from the ground its change in kinetic energy is zero. That means the net work done on the book is zero. You did positive work of $mgh$ raising the book but gravity did an equal amount of negative work of $-mgh$ (because its force is opposite to the displacement of the book). So the net work done on the book is zero.

So where did the energy you gave the book go? Gravity took that energy and stored it as gravitational potential energy in the Earth-book system.

Hope this helps.